# Is it possible to pass a datatype with a particular property in csv2geojson.js?

Tags: csv, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I am using https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson API to convert CSV file to GeoJSON and then trying to use data-driven coloring to interpolate a property. 
 csv2geojson.js converts all the other values to strings by default. Is there a way to pass a particular datatype for a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code, there's no support for other data types. But you could add it fairly easily by changing [this line](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson/blob/gh-pages/index.js#L107):

```
var parsed = (typeof x == 'string') ?
    dsv.dsvFormat(options.delimiter).parse(x) : x;
```

You need to parse a [row conversion function](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse) to `.parse()`.